# UPDATE CART ITEMS USING AJAX IN MAGENTO

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to update the cart item without loading the page i.e with the help of ajax.
can anyone tell me in which file did i put this code.

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#shopping-cart-table')
     .on(
          'change',
          'input[name$="[qty]"]',
           function(){
            var form = jQuery(jQuery(this).closest('form'));

             // we'll extract the action and method attributes out of the form

              // kick off an ajax request using the form's action and method,
        // with the form data as payload
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            method: form.attr('method'),
            data: form.serializeArray()
        });
    }
);
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is to put this code in a **Javascript** script tag into the checkout cart template: *magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/cart.phtml*

Be carefull, you have to set `update_cart_action` data to `"update_qty"`, to be in update qty mode.

```
var formData = form.serializeArray();
formData.push({'update_cart_action' : 'update_qty'})

jQuery.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'),
     method: form.attr('method'),
     data: formData
});
```

Comment: can you give me the code of overridded cartController of action updatePostAction().

Comment: You don't need to override cartController. Just push the value of update_cart_action into your ajax data: